# Docker will not start automatically after reboot on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I have docker installed on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.
This is the Docker info:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:37 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

I would like to have docker start automatically whenever the server starts, but i consistently get this message at startup:

```
Service is not running
Docker Desktop service is not running, would you like to start it? Windows will ask you for elevated access.
```

in order to start docker, i will have to press start manually through the GUI, but i would like to automate this process.

I have already tried:

```
-Logging in with my account on this machine
-Put docker shortcut at shell:startup folder
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using
"net start com.docker.service" before starting the docker.exe process works.